# Unmet dependencies for OpenGL

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvidia-graphics-card, opengl

I recently tried out the `xorg-edgers` ppa for `Nvidia-352` driver and it kind of screwed things up, so I removed it. Now, I can't `make` or install things I used to be able to. I am trying to make the `2_graphics/Mandelbrot` example as part of the `CUDA` 6.5 samples. I know this *should* work because it worked when I just used the `Nvidia-331` package installation from `Ubuntu`.

When I attempt to `make`, I get:

```
>>> WARNING - gl.h not found, refer to CUDA Samples release notes for how to find and install them. <<<
>>> WARNING - glu.h not found, refer to CUDA Samples release notes for how to find and install them. <<<
```

A simple googling clued me in that I may need to `apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev`, but when I do, I get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libglu1-mesa-dev : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dev or
                             libgl-dev
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I try installing these packages, each one tells me something along the lines of "These are virtual packages, specify one by name" or the same `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Is this a lingering problem from the `xorg-edgers` ppa? If so, how do I get rid of it?

EDIT: before anyone asks, yes - I have tried `apt-get update`, `apt-get autoremove`, `apt-get upgrade`, and many others.

Comment: And have you tried `apt-get -f install`?

Comment: yes - I had to do that to fix things when `xedgers` broke things. It doesn't fix the problem now though.

Comment: Could you pls post the exact output of `apt-get -f install`?

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: How about choosing the version of libgl1-mesa-dev suitable to your Ubuntu version, like libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-quantal?

Comment: That tells me it depends on `lbgl1-mesa-dev` ... when I try for `libgl1-mesa-dev`, it tell sme it depends on `mesa-common-dev` and `libdrm-dev` ... I can keep chasing these dependencies, but each one tells me that I have held broken packages and I just don't think that is the correct way to go about this.

Comment: You are right. Try reading this answer, see if any of this helps. http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa

Comment: I tried all of those before I posted the question ... Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25463/discussion-between-laurbert515-and-mariusmatutiae).